# Run truffle migration without using the cli

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, truffle

I am trying to build a simple node js backend that deploys compiled smart contracts to a testnet. I am able to compile and migrate my contracts with truffle through the cli but what I would like to achieve is to run the migrations inside my API in node js. I have been digging into truffle packages for hours but found nothing on how to do that.

What I understood is that the migrations are performed by an object called deployer and that there is a package called @truffle/deployer. The thing is I don't know how properly create one.

The alternative would be to use web3js for deployment which has a much trickier process.

has anybody performed truffle mifrations in a javascript script instead of using `truffle migrate` in the terminal before?

Comment: I don't know the solution right now, but it seems that the migration JS is in the `migrate` package (https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/blob/develop/packages/migrate/index.js#L11) - not in the `deployer`.

Comment: that I also noticed. It says that it is used innside the migrate command in the core package. But I checked in the truffle core package and jn the index.js there is no migrate command

Comment: The `truffle` command (and its params, such as `migrate`) is invoked from `./node_modules/.bin/truffle`. The `migrate` param then links to a webpack module, most likely a wrapper of the package mentioned in my previous comment. As you can see in the migrate package source, it states in a comment that it's used as part of `truffle migrate`. My guess is that the `truffle` script effectively executes some of the `migrate` script functions in series - maybe first  `needsMigrating` to validate, and then `runMigrations`.